# Restarting webpack-dev-server after modifying eslint rules

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, eslint

Can I force the reload of webpack-dev-server anytime. Even if I modify white-spaces. These changes are not code-related but they are needed for eslint validation.

When eslint reports wrong formatting, whitespaces etc. and I fix it, the dev-server skips the update with a message "Nothing changed". So that the code seems to be broken even it's not.

[image]

I use:

- webpack-dev-server (1.14.1)
- eslint-loader (1.3.0)
- eslint (2.9.0)

My configuration looks this way:

```
loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
            },
```

Thank you.

Comment: You want to watch `.eslintrc` rules and reload webpack? It is possible, but probably worth only on environment setup process at the beginning of project. It's normal to restart by hand webpack after modify webpack config (include eslint rules). After 1 or 2 days you will forget about this and work normally without tweaking in webpack config. In my opinion is not worth it - **it simply add noise to your tooling setup**.

Comment: No, it's not about config. I mean the code. The case is: 1.) I write a JS code. 2) it said "no-trailing-spaces". 3) I fix the error. 4) It said "nothing changed" because it is only a white-space and so that the code is not updated.

Comment: You should update this clarification info in question - i totally missed your point. And consider if new title is valid since I made it before your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using webpack 1, it still uses the new `NewWatchingPlugin()` by default in the latest version. You can use the old version of it:
`js
plugins: [ new webpack.OldWatchingPlugin() ]`